# Javascript function call in asp.net page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have taken 1 textbox, 1 button and 1 alert image in my asp.net page. And I have written JavaScript function and call it in onblur and onclick event of text box. The function of onblur is that if the textbox is empty then the alert picture will show else picture will hide. And in onclick picture will hide. And another JavaScript function I also used to hide the picture when I open the page first time. I call this in pageload of aspx.cs page

Same things I want to do in my button Onclientclick event but it is not working because when I clicked on button the page is loaded.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
        function onblur_check(id, pic) {

            if (document.getElementById(id).value == "") {
                alert(pic);
                document.getElementById(pic).style.display = "block";
            }
            else {
                alert(document.getElementById(id).value);
                document.getElementById(pic).style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        function onclick_check(id, pic) {
            document.getElementById(pic).style.display = "none";
        }

Answer (score -1):

Your button click is causing postback. The simple way without seeing your code, at the end of javascript function that onclick is invoking, before the closing bracket - return false.

From the code you shared, do return false after alert();

Comment: Are you voting down me without any reasonable reason? stackoverflow will ban you, be sure.

Comment: @eddyuk it is my coding
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function onblur_check(id, pic) 
{ 
 if (document.getElementById(id).value == "") 
 {   
  document.getElementById(pic).style.display = "block"; 
 }
  else 
 { 
  alert(document.getElementById(id).value);
  document.getElementById(pic).style.display = "none"; 
 } 
} 
function onclick_check(id, pic) 
 { 
  document.getElementById(pic).style.display = "none"; 
 } 


OnClientClick="save_reg_details(ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_first_name.id,'img_firstname');return false;"                    onclick="btn_save_Click"/>
Now onclick is not working

Comment: Why you chain it to the save_reg_details method? place it inside just before closing bracket. I don't think it's syntax is valid to place it OnClientClick

Comment: function save_reg_details(id, pic) {
    if (document.getElementById(id).value == "") {
        document.getElementById(pic).style.display = "block";
    } else {
        alert(document.getElementById(id).value);
        document.getElementById(pic).style.display = "none";
    }
    return false;
}

Comment: and remove return false from OnClientClick="save_reg_details(ContentPlaceHolder1_txt_first_name.id,'img_first‌​name'); return false;